# 'NameError: name 'importos' is not defined' when loading GeoJSON file QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geojson, import, mac, vector-layer

I am trying to load a GeoJSON file in QGIS. But I am reaching some difficulties (I am on Mac Os). I am using the following code:

```py
import os
import glob

json_paths = glob.glob(r"/Users/name/Downloads/Sport.geojson")
layer_paths = list()  # List of layer paths to load

for json_path in json_paths:
  layer = QgsVectorLayer(json_path, "", "ogr")
```

Unfortunately, the code does not seem to work.
I have that error:

```
File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'importos' is not defined
```

I have tried different codes but each time the error is quite similar.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.5\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'importos' is not defined
```

This error occurred because the `importos` was mistyped. And now Python tries to interpret it as `importos` variable, which is not defined. It should be `import os` instead.

Besides that your code works well.

```py
import os
import glob

json_paths = glob.glob("C:/Documents/Python Scripts/test.geojson")
layer_paths = list()  # List of layer paths to load

for json_path in json_paths:
  layer = QgsVectorLayer(json_path, "test", "ogr")
  registry = QgsProject.instance()
  registry.addMapLayer(layer)
```

I tested it with this GeoJSON: https://datahub.io/examples/geojson-tutorial/r/example.geojson

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with your example that works perfectly. For information on **macOs** I had to use this path "/Users/Me/Downloads/export.geojson".